# Pointers, Double Pointers, Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

in the following code, we were asked to determine what the output of the code would be.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
int     x = -1;
int     y = -1;
int     **pp;
int     *pi[2];

pi[0] = &x;
pi[1] = &y;
*pi[0] = 4;
*pi[1] = 5;
printf ("A:  %d  %d\n",  x, y);
pp = pi;    // HINT: same as pp=&pi[0];

**pp++ = 90;
**pp   = 75;
pi[0]  = &y;
**--pp = 35;
printf ("B:  %d  %d\n",  x, y);

return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to be:

A: 4 5

B: 90 35

I do understand the 4 5 but not B. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: There is no pointer to `double`. You mean "pointer to pointer"! And we are no "do my homework" service. See [ask].

Comment: Draw it out on a piece of paper. I think visually about pointers, and with a little practice, it is easy to do it in your head.

Comment: Hi Olaf, this was actually on a recent quiz for me, and i just didn't get how to do B. Not trying to get you to do my homework, just needed some help figuring it out to satisfy my curiosity. As well, a pointer that points to a pointer can be referred to as a double pointer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this problem is WHEN the increment and decrement occur.  Because it is a post-increment on the line:

```
**pp++ = 90;
```

the contents of the original pointer is being modified (&x) then pp points at pi[1]. Then pi[0] is set to the address of y:

```
pi[0] = &y;
```

Finally, pp is pre-decrimented and pointing at pi[0] which points to y and then it is updated.

```
**--pp = 35;
```

**Edit:** Modified to say "the contents of the original pointer"

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Makes sense to me now

Answer (score 0):

In this expression you point pp to pi array of pointers.

```
pp = pi;
```

Here you dereference pp (**pp is pointing at pi[0] wich is pointer to x) and then you asaign 90. So you get value 90 in x. And at the and you increment pointer pp and now it's pointing to pi[1].

```
**pp++ = 90;
```

It's same as previouse step but at this moment your pp is pointing to pi[1] wich is pointer to y. So now y is 75. But this time you don't increment pointer so pp is still pointing to pi[1] wich is y.

```
**pp = 75;
```

In this step you asaign 35 to y and after that you decrement pointer to pi[0]. So now your value in y is 35.

```
**--pp = 35;
```

At the end you have x == 90 and y == 35.

Comment: Thank you! This was really easy to understand! I really appreciate it